# Trying to skip columns in loop if requirement isn't satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, similarity

I have this python code trying to find similarities between brands based on the types of products they sell and at what price point. One issue I'm running into is price, sales, and number of products are independent of the columns before. What I want to happen is as soon as one of the columns doesn't match, go to the next row because of the category isn't the same, I don't want to give it extra weighting points for being the same price/number of products/sales. I left the brand that's creating brand_df in the original df as a baseline because that should technically have the highest score.

This is the code I used. I tried adding the continue function, but I don't think it's working

```py
def subproducts_weighted(brand, df):
    brand_df = df.loc[df['BRAND'] == brand]

    weights = {
        'L1': 5.0,
        'L2': 5.0,
        'L3': 4.0,
        'L4': 3.0,
        'L5': 2.0,
        'Price': 3.0,
        'Sales': 5.0,
        'Product_count': 3.0
    }

    allowed_percentage_difference = 0.1 

    max_possible_sum = sum(weights.values())

    # Create a list to store DataFrames and concatenate them later
    result_dfs = []

    for _, brand_row in brand_df.iterrows():
        for _, row in df.iterrows():
            weighted_sum = 0
            
            for column, weight in weights.items():
                if column not in ['Price', 'Sales', 'Product_count']:
                    if row[column] != brand_row[column]:
                        continue
                    elif row[column] == "NA" and brand_row[column] == "NA":
                        weighted_sum
                    else:
                        weighted_sum += (row[column] == brand_row[column]) * weight
                if column in ['Price', 'Sales', 'Product_count']:
                    product_value = float(brand_row[column])
                    allowed_range = (
                        product_value * (1 - allowed_percentage_difference),
                        product_value * (1 + allowed_percentage_difference)
                        )

                    weighted_sum += ((row[column] >= allowed_range[0]) & (row[column] <= allowed_range[1])) * weight
                    

            row_data = {'BRAND': row['BRAND'], 'weighted_sum': (weighted_sum / max_possible_sum) * 100}
            result_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([row_data]))

    # Concatenate the list of DataFrames into the final result
    result_df = pd.concat(result_dfs, ignore_index=True)

    # Sort the result DataFrame
    result_df = result_df.sort_values('weighted_sum', ascending=False)

    return result_df
```

Answer (score 1):

A `continue` will only skip the current iteration, using `break` instead will exit the column for loop and go to the next row.

Your code will look like this (where inner `for loop` will be terminated by using `break` in case of (`if`) a mismatch is found, then `else` block after the column loop is executed only if the loop completes normally, without a `break`. Based on this answer your code might look like this:

```
def subproducts_weighted(brand, df):
    brand_df = df.loc[df['BRAND'] == brand]

    weights = {
        'L1': 5.0,
        'L2': 5.0,
        'L3': 4.0,
        'L4': 3.0,
        'L5': 2.0,
        'Price': 3.0,
        'Sales': 5.0,
        'Product_count': 3.0
    }

    allowed_percentage_difference = 0.1
    max_possible_sum = sum(weights.values())

    result_dfs = []

    for _, brand_row in brand_df.iterrows():
        for _, row in df.iterrows():
            weighted_sum = 0

            for column, weight in weights.items():
                if column not in ['Price', 'Sales', 'Product_count']:
                    if row[column] != brand_row[column]:
                        break
                else:
                    product_value = float(brand_row[column])
                    allowed_range = (
                        product_value * (1 - allowed_percentage_difference),
                        product_value * (1 + allowed_percentage_difference)
                    )

                    if not (row[column] >= allowed_range[0] and row[column] <= allowed_range[1]):
                        break

                weighted_sum += weight
            else:  # This else corresponds to the for-loop, executed if no break occurs
                row_data = {'BRAND': row['BRAND'], 'weighted_sum': (weighted_sum / max_possible_sum) * 100}
                result_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([row_data]))

    result_df = pd.concat(result_dfs, ignore_index=True)
    result_df = result_df.sort_values('weighted_sum', ascending=False)

    return result_df
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Since OP said my statement of what's the goal is correct:
"what you're trying to achieve is to compare the input brand with other brands and then to do calculation (regarding to their similarity score based on criteria), and in case there's missmatch in the categories of any levels (L1,L2,L3,L4, etc..)- you stop immediately and then score should not include weights from subsequent cats, such as price?"

This is updated code:

```
def subproducts_weighted(brand, df):
    brand_df = df.loc[df['BRAND'] == brand].iloc[0]  # Assuming only one row per brand

    weights = {
        'L1': 5.0,
        'L2': 5.0,
        'L3': 4.0,
        'L4': 3.0,
        'L5': 2.0,
        'Price': 3.0,
        'Sales': 5.0,
        'Product_count': 3.0
    }

    max_possible_sum = sum(weights.values())
    result_dfs = []

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['BRAND'] == brand:  # Skip the comparison brand itself
            continue

        weighted_sum = 0

        for column, weight in weights.items():
            if column not in ['Price', 'Sales', 'Product_count']:
                if row[column] != brand_df[column]:
                    break
            else:
                # For Price, Sales, and Product_count, we consider exact match only
                if row[column] != brand_df[column]:
                    break

            weighted_sum += weight

        else:  # This else is executed only if no break occurs in the for-loop
            row_data = {'BRAND': row['BRAND'], 'weighted_sum': (weighted_sum / max_possible_sum) * 100}
            result_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([row_data]))

    result_df = pd.concat(result_dfs, ignore_index=True)
    result_df = result_df.sort_values('weighted_sum', ascending=False)

    return result_df
```

And to pinpoint "critical" changes:

- Used `brand_df.iloc[0]` to get a single row for the comparison brand.
- Added a condition to skip the comparison with the same brand.
- Removed the `allowed_percentage_difference` as it's not used in this context.
- Simplified the weight addition and breaking logic.

Comment: This answer is actually , I actually must say that I like this approach better than mine, it's more straightforward than introducing flag. I will edit your answer to provide code.

Comment: I like this! My only issue is that it's only returning the score for the inputted brand rather than all other brands. What I would like this to do is say my inputted brand is candy at l1, chocolate at l2, milk chocolate at l3, bar at l4, $2 price and the comparison brand A is  candy at l1, chocolate at l2, dark chocolate at l3, piece at l4, $2 price, then the comparison brand B would output a weight of 10 because as soon as it stops matching at l2 it will stop and not add to the weight for having the same price, so it would return brand B weighted_sum: 10

Comment: I don't know if I understand this enough, but what you're trying to achieve is to compare the input brand with other brands and then to do calculation (regarding to their similarity score based on criteria), and in case there's missmatch in the categories  of any levels (L1,L2,L3,L4, etc..)- you stop immediately and then score should not include weights from subsequent cats, such as price?  @krizik

Comment: @str1ng that's correct

Comment: @krizik I just updated this answer (when it comes to code), but until the edit is approved by OP or somebody else unfortunately you won't be able to see it.

Comment: @str1ng all approved :)

Answer (score 0):

To address the **issue itself** here lies within your `loops` and `conditionals` (in their structure).

What you want to do is to skip to the next `row` as soon as one of the `columns` **doesn't match**, but what you're doing with current code is totally different - you're skipping the current `iteration` of the `innermost loop` and not the entire `row`.

To solve it, the most basic approach, and the one that is easiest to understand  (in my opinion) is by having so called "`flag` variable", which plays role of `indicator` - which is going to say whether you should skip the rest of the column checks for the current `row` or no.

In the code below, I will introduce `skip_row` flag which is either going to be `False` (default value will be `False`) or be set to `True` meanwhile.

Therefore, this code should be working fine:

```
def subproducts_weighted(brand, df):
    brand_df = df.loc[df['BRAND'] == brand]

    weights = {
        'L1': 5.0,
        'L2': 5.0,
        'L3': 4.0,
        'L4': 3.0,
        'L5': 2.0,
        'Price': 3.0,
        'Sales': 5.0,
        'Product_count': 3.0
    }

    allowed_percentage_difference = 0.1
    max_possible_sum = sum(weights.values())

    result_dfs = []

    for _, brand_row in brand_df.iterrows():
        for _, row in df.iterrows():
            weighted_sum = 0
            skip_row = False

            for column, weight in weights.items():
                if skip_row:
                    break

                if column not in ['Price', 'Sales', 'Product_count']:
                    if row[column] != brand_row[column]:
                        skip_row = True
                        continue
                else:
                    product_value = float(brand_row[column])
                    allowed_range = (
                        product_value * (1 - allowed_percentage_difference),
                        product_value * (1 + allowed_percentage_difference)
                    )

                    if not (row[column] >= allowed_range[0] and row[column] <= allowed_range[1]):
                        skip_row = True
                        continue

                weighted_sum += weight

            if not skip_row:
                row_data = {'BRAND': row['BRAND'], 'weighted_sum': (weighted_sum / max_possible_sum) * 100}
                result_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([row_data]))

    result_df = pd.concat(result_dfs, ignore_index=True)
    result_df = result_df.sort_values('weighted_sum', ascending=False)

    return result_df
```